# Meaning of kaomoji: ﾖﾛ(｀・ω・´)ｽｸ！

Tags: meaning, expressions, katakana, kana, internet-slang

I’ve encountered this kaomoji:

> ﾖﾛ(｀・ω・´)ｽｸ！

quite a few times already:

[image: ﾖﾛ(｀・ω・´)ｽｸ！ in a game]

[image: ﾖﾛ(｀・ω・´)ｽｸ！ YouTube Query]

However, I’m stumped as to what it could mean. I have noticed the half-width katakana「ヨロ」and「スク」, but am unclear on what word/words they are referring to.

Comment: Not really an answer but: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10119116570

Comment: 「はじめまして！」を「はじめま**す**て！」って書いてる人も見ますね・・東北弁のマネかと思いましたが。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means ヨロシク, here mistyping/mispronouncing add a Funny/Cute tone.